# Vec<> push & concat vs append vs extend_from_slice

Tags: rust

I'm constructing a single `Vec<f64>` out of smaller `Vec<f64>`s and can't quite understand which is the right way to do it.

Here are three attempts with commentary on each:

```
fn main() {
    // this vector will be getting changed so is mutable
    let mut a:Vec<Vec<f64>> = vec![];

    // these won't be getting changed, they gets appended to `a`
    let b = vec![0.0, 1.0];
    let c = vec![2.0, 3.0];

    a.push(b);
    a.push(c);
    
    // and then the vector gets flattened into the form that I require:
    dbg!(a.concat());

    // however, if I want a single level vector constructed from other vectors
    let mut d:Vec<f64> = vec![];

    // b and c have to be mutable, why is that?
    // their contents don't change?
    // why can't they just be consumed?
    let mut e = vec![0.0, 1.0];
    let mut f = vec![2.0, 3.0];

    d.append(&mut e);
    d.append(&mut f);

    dbg!(d);

    // another method is to extend from slice
    // does this have performance problems compared to the other methods due
    // to the copying required?
    let mut g:Vec<f64> = vec![];
    
    let h = vec![0.0, 1.0];
    let i = vec![2.0, 3.0];

    g.extend_from_slice(&h);
    g.extend_from_slice(&i);

    dbg!(g);

}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:15] a.concat() = [
    0.0,
    1.0,
    2.0,
    3.0,
]
[src/main.rs:28] d = [
    0.0,
    1.0,
    2.0,
    3.0,
]
[src/main.rs:46] g = [
    0.0,
    1.0,
    2.0,
    3.0,
]
```

I'm leaning towards `extend_from_slice` as it communicates to the reader of the code that vectors `h` & `i` will not be changing.

But my question is: is there a performance hit due to the copying? Is there a way to just consume the data when appending without making vectors `e` & `f` mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is `append` will move each item from one `Vec` to another, `extend_from_slice` will clone each item.

In terms of performance between the two, in your case there is a slight difference as even though a clone and copy of a `f64` [is the same](https://godbolt.org/z/qnbv4jron), `append` uses [std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html) witch is equivalent to `memcpy`, and `extend_from_slice` iterates over and clones each item.

Where performance really matters when the source `Vec` contains values with dynamic memory and want to avoid the re-allocation that comes with clone (such as `String`) or the source `Vec` is large.

The reason the source to `append` needs to be mutable is because it is mutating its inner state by moving the values out and setting its length to 0.

I would say that `concat` is for a different use case where the number of source structs is unknown, and is likely to have worse performance due to it needing to iterate over all items.

Answer (score 0):

`append()` empties the source `Vec`s, so it needs to take them as `&mut`. It does not move them because you may still want to use their allocated memory.

In terms of performance, all methods use plain `memcpy()` - `append()` because it moves the items and the other methods because they're specialized to use a simple copy for `Copy` items. However, `append()` and `extend_from_slice()` grow the vector twice, for each addition, while `concat()` calculates the required capacity ahead of time so it is likely to be faster.